# Highly volatile server communication with BOTH TCP and UDP connections?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, client-server

I'm trying to stream sensor data from my Arduino (server), over my network, to my computer (client) in real-time.

While sensor data is coming in at a consistent rate per second, the time between messages is highly irregular.

I tested both UDP and TCP connections with both one directional and bidirectional communication on minimal examples to isolate this behavior.

I also tried adding delays, using different settings (SOCK_STREAM vs TCP_NO_DELAY), decreasing the message size, and adding headers to the message in attempt to synchronize the connection, if that was the issue.

**In every case, the messages come in consistent, but in inconsistent burst like this:**

[image]

*message is always "test", frame number printed instead for illustration

#### Why is this happening and how can I make time between messages more consistent/stable?

---

## Below are the bare minimum examples I tested on:

###### One Directional (server -> client)

**TCP Client**

```
    import time
    import socket
    
    ADDRESS = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    PORT = 80
    SIZE = 4
    
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.TCP_NODELAY)
    sock.connect((ADDRESS, PORT))
    
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    sock.recv(SIZE)
    print("Connected")
    
    t0 = 0
    f = 0
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(SIZE).decode()
        if f == 0:
            t0 = time.time()
            time.sleep(.0001)
    
        f += 1
        fps = int(f / (time.time() - t0))
        print(f"\r{f} FPS: {fps} data: {data}   ", end='')
```

**TCP Server**

```
    #include <WiFiNINA.h>
    
    WiFiServer server(80);
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
      while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        status = WiFi.begin("ssid", "password");
        delay(1000);
      }
      server.begin();
    
      Serial.println("connected");
      Serial.print("SSID: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
      IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
      Serial.println(ip);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      server.write("test");
      delay(16);
    }
```

**UDP Client**

```
import socket
import time

ADDRESS = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
PORT = 2390
SIZE = 4

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(b"s", (ADDRESS, PORT))

print("Waiting for connection...")
sock.recvfrom(SIZE)
print("Connected")

t0 = 0
f = 0
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(SIZE)
    data = data.decode()
    if f == 0:
        t0 = time.time()
        time.sleep(.0001)
    
    f += 1
    fps = int(f / (time.time() - t0))
    print(f"\r{f} FPS: {fps} data: {data}   ", end='')
```

**UDP Server**

```
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    status = WiFi.begin("ssid", "password");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Udp.begin(2390);

  Serial.println("connected");
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void loop() {
  Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
  Udp.write("test");
  Udp.endPacket();
  delay(16);
}
```

###### Bi Directional (server <> client)

**TCP Client**

```
import time
import socket

ADDRESS = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
PORT = 80
SIZE = 4

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.TCP_NODELAY)
sock.connect((ADDRESS, PORT))

print("Waiting for connection...")
sock.send(b's')
sock.recv(SIZE)
print("Connected")

t0 = 0
f = 0
while True:
    sock.send(b's')
    data = sock.recv(SIZE).decode()
    if f == 0:
        t0 = time.time()
        time.sleep(.0001)

    f += 1
    fps = int(f / (time.time() - t0))
    print(f"\r{f} FPS: {fps} data: {data}   ", end='')
```

**TCP Server**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>

WiFiServer server(80);

boolean alreadyConnected = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi... ");
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    status = WiFi.begin("ssid", "password");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("connected.");
  server.begin();

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (!alreadyConnected) {
      client.flush();
      alreadyConnected = true;
    }
    if (client.available() > 0) {
      char thisChar = client.read();
      client.write("test");
    }
  }
}
```

**UDP Client**

```
import socket
import time

ADDRESS = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
PORT = 2390
SIZE = 4

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(b"s", (ADDRESS, PORT))

print("Waiting for connection...")
sock.recvfrom(SIZE)
print("Connected")

t0 = 0
f = 0
while True:
    sock.sendto(b"s", (ADDRESS, PORT))
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(SIZE)
    data = data.decode()
    if f == 0:
        t0 = time.time()
        time.sleep(.0001)
    
    f += 1
    fps = int(f / (time.time() - t0))
    print(f"\r{f} FPS: {fps} data: {data}   ", end='')
```

**UDP Server**

```
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wifi... ");
  int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    status = WiFi.begin("wifi", "password");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("connnected.");
  Udp.begin(2390);

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void loop() {
  if (!Udp.parsePacket()) {
    return;
  }

  while (Udp.read() != -1);
  Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
  Udp.write("test");
  Udp.endPacket();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a network or hardware problem, not a code problem.

Comment: The first thing I would do is rewrite your test programs in C, to rule out the Python interpreter as a culprit.  (Python isn’t known for its speed)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner while Python may be slower than other languages, I'm not asking it to break encryption here. Receiving 4 bytes over socket at a consistent rate of at least 15 fps should be more than doable

Comment: How is your arduino connected to the server? I ask because it may be something in the physical layer.

Comment: @hugos I'm using an Arduino MKR wifi 1010 with a built in u-blox NINA-W102 radio module, so not any additional/external hardware to create the server

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Another question: is the client running in your local machine or are you connected through SSH?

Comment: The reason this matters is that the jitter you observe might be due to the output itself. You are writing a new line for every incoming packet and SSH can be slow to catch up.

Comment: @hugos local machine :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253617/discussion-between-hugos-and-dandev).

Comment: @dandev agreed; my concern is that maybe once in a while the Python interpreter takes a little break to do some garbage collection, or something like that.